# Mapping of multiple table data to single bean in Spring jdbc

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jdbc, db2

Data of multiple tables has to be mapped to single bean.

In this case `id,name` will be retrieved from one table, `optionList` from other table. So data from n number of tables should be matched to single bean. What would be the best approach using `RowMapper or ResultSetExtractor or any alternative`. What would be the performance difference between 
**BeanPropertyRowMapper and RowMapper**.

My model class is like:

```
class Preference{
    int id;
    int name;
    List<Option> optionList; //will be retrieved from other table.
    String contactName;
    String ContactTitle; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Spring Row Mapper to do the job.
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#jdbc-JdbcTemplate-examples-query

Pretty much some like

```
public class MyRowMapper implements RowMapper<MyCustomEntity> {

    @Override
    public MyCustomEntity mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        MyCustomEntity custom = new MyCustomEntity();

        custom.setId(rs.getLong("id"));
        custom.setName(rs.getString("name"));
        custom.setMoreData(rs.getString("more_data"));

        return custom;
    }

}
```

In your DAO guy, you can do something like

```
@Repository
public class DaoGuy {

    @Inject
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public List<MyCustomEntity> getMyCustomEntityData(String whateverYouWantToUseToFilter) {
        String sqlQuery = "select a.id, b.name, c.more_data from my tablea a, tableb b, tablec c";
        return jdbcTemplate.query(sqlQuery, new MyRowMapper());

    }

}
```